# Verificar se valor existe antes de fazer update

Tags: postgresql

Preciso fazer uma *query* para atualizar uma coluna, mas só deve atualizar a coluna se o dado a ser atualizado não existir atualmente naquela coluna.

Comment: Se não existir o que?

Comment: simplesmente não faz nada, so quero que faça udpate se esse não existir na tabela já, eu sou consigo arranjar com update if not exist insert

Comment: Pelo que entendi o que você quer é um `INSERT` caso o registro não exita na tabela.

Comment: não, eu quero fazer um update a um campo. mas não quero valores repetidos.

Comment: Especifique. Dê exemplo do que quer. Se você não quer valores repetidos em uma coluna, então determine que ela deva ser `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Olá Miguel! Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow. Por favor, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como obter melhores respostas. Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, precisa detalhar melhor.  Coloque o comando SQL que tentou fazer, um exemplo de como gostaria que as informações ficassem após o update, etc. Precisamos de mais informações para te ajudar.

Comment: temos uma tabela com estes dados Joao Luis e Joao Sousa, quero fazer um update ao Joao Luis quero mudar tambem para Joao Sousa mas so vai fazer esse update se na tabela nao existis se exisitir não faz nada.

Comment: @MiguelLourenço, deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer fazer um update em uma coluna de uma tabela apenas se o valor a ser atualizado não existir atualmente naquela coluna da tabela. Seria isso?

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim é isso! obrigado

Answer (score 4):

O ideal é deixar o campo `UNIQUE`, mas se por algum motivo você precisa fazer, pode usar uma query parecida com essa:

```
UPDATE 
    suatabela 
SET 
    seucampo = 'seuvalor' 
WHERE 
    seucampo NOT IN (SELECT 
                        COUNT(seucampo) 
                    FROM 
                        suatabela 
                    WHERE 
                        seucampo = 'seuvalor')
```

Comment: Verificar se valor existe antes de fazer update, é isto que eu quero fazer

Comment: não é isto que pretendo